# RateLimiter как получить количество оставшихся попыток (X-RateLimit-Remaining)?

Tags: php, laravel

Как получить количество оставшихся попыток (X-RateLimit-Remaining) со стороны сервера? Что бы например вывести юзеру в профиле.

Небольшой пример:

RouteServiceProvider

```
RateLimiter::for('test', function (Request $request) {
    Limit::perMinute(10)->by('test');
});
```

Маршрут

```
Route::middleware(['throttle:test'])->get('test', function () {
    return RateLimiter::attempts('test');  //Так не выводит result: 0
    //return Cache::get('test');                 //Так тоже пусто
});
```

Вроде как в кеше должно хранится, но не понятно почему не могу получить? Хотя сам RateLimiter работает если сделать запрос то в header есть данные о количестве оставшихся запросов. laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете получить количество оставшихся попыток, вызвав метод [`remaining`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.html#method_remaining):

```py
RateLimiter::remaining('test', $perMinute = 10);
```

Соответствующий раздел документации: [Manually Incrementing Attempts](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/rate-limiting#manually-incrementing-attempts).

Comment: уже пробовал, дело в том что в функции remaining используется функция attempts. А так как attempts Выводит всегда result 0, следовательно remaining всегда выводит указанный maxAttempts

    public function remaining($key, $maxAttempts)
    {
        $attempts = $this->attempts($key);

        return $maxAttempts - $attempts;
    }

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php#L156

Comment: @МихаилПетров Так всё верно… Если пользователь ни разу не пытался, то у него остаётся максимальное количество попыток

Comment: нет, конкретно attempts почему то не работает если я пытаюсь на стороне сервера узнать, если я смотру в header через postman то там все в порядке
X-RateLimit-Limit: 10
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 3

Comment: Я понял! Пришлось расковырять header!
В общем attempts и remaining принимает не $key, a $limiterName.$limit->key
В моем случае это не 'test', a 'testtest'
Вот так все работает:
return RateLimiter::remaining(md5('testtest'), $perMinute = 10);

Answer (score 0):

Ответ:

RouteServiceProvider

```
RateLimiter::for('test', function (Request $request) {
    Limit::perMinute(10)->by('test');
});
```

Маршрут

```
Route::middleware(['throttle:test'])->get('test', function () {
        $limiterName = 'test';
        $limit_key = 'test';
        $key = md5($limiterName.$limit_key);
        return RateLimiter::attempts($key);
    });
```